# KML open image, Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

I'm playing around with KML a little.
I am creating a placemark that shows an image when clicked. When I right click on the image there is an option to open it but Google Earth fails to open the image. Is there a way to make Google Earth open it?
The KML uses a relative path to the image and there is no problem showing the image this way in a balloon but when I click the "Open Image" option it fails to open.
If anyone has any help i would really appreciate it.
Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
<name>Photos.kml</name>
<Folder>
    <name>Photos</name>

    <Style id="Photo">
        <IconStyle>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://www.google.com/mapfiles/arrow.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <scale>.7</scale> 
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>

    <Placemark>
        <name>IMG_0988.JPG</name>

        <description><![CDATA[<div align="center"><table width="500"><tr><td colspan="2"><center><img src="pics/IMG_0988.jpg" width="500" height="373"></td></tr></table></div>]]></description>

        <styleUrl>#Photo</styleUrl>

        <Point>
            <coordinates>13.18733333,60.66783333000001,0</coordinates>
        </Point>

        <Style>
            <IconStyle>
                <heading>90</heading>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>

    </Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Have you tried making a KMZ file and adding the image as part of the KMZ file in appropriate sub-folder ? Also, doesn't matter much to google earth but there's a <center> start tag w/o an end tag in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks! Must have missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you also wrap the `<img>` tag with `<a href="">..</a>` with the same image URL. If you right-click image in the balloon, Google Earth will then give you some additional options: Open Link, Open in New Window, Copy Link.

The Open Image works in GE 7.0 with a test image. Results might vary whether you have "*Show web results in external browser*" option checked under *Tools/Options/General* or not.

```
<description>
    <![CDATA[<div align="center"><table width="500"><tr><td>
    <a href="pics/IMG_0988.jpg"><img src="pics/IMG_0988.jpg" width="500" height="373"></a>
    </td></tr></table></div>]]>
</description>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that doesn't help me. I'm still isn't able to open an image from clicking on the image or clicking "Open image".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this exactly your issue, but I just figured out a pretty frustrating quirk with Google Earth that's related to embedding links to full-size images in the description element.

Basically, it appears that Google Earth requires the extension to be lowercase (e.g. jpg instead of JPG) to display in the bubble, even if the file has the uppercase extension.

Right-click open-image works with both capitalizations.

For example, I have a file named "2015_03_27 G11/IMG_8320.JPG" that I want to display with a placemark:

Appears to work on Windows:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>IMG_8320.JPG</name>
    <description>&lt;img src='2015_03_27 G11/IMG_8320.jpg' width='600' height='450'/&gt;</description>
    <styleUrl>#defaultStyle1</styleUrl>
    <Style>
        <IconStyle>
            <Icon>
                <href>kml-thumbs/thumb-2015_03_27_G11-IMG_8320.JPG</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Point>
        <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        <coordinates>10.705401,104.773769,27</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

DOES NOT WORK (at least on Windows)

```
<Placemark>
    <name>IMG_8320.JPG</name>
    <description>&lt;img src='2015_03_27 G11/IMG_8320.JPG' width='600' height='450'/&gt;</description>
    <styleUrl>#defaultStyle1</styleUrl>
    <Style>
        <IconStyle>
            <Icon>
                <href>kml-thumbs/thumb-2015_03_27_G11-IMG_8320.JPG</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Point>
        <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        <coordinates>10.705401,104.773769,27</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```